# Mirror of gRPC calls

Tags: c#, grpc

I want to be able to mirror all gRPC calls for some services to another set of services with same interface, in C#.
I think about writing extension method for GrpcClientFactory.CreateClient, to return class which would do two calls in parallel. Result from mirror is not needed, so I would return result from first call.
Is it best aproach for the task, or it is possible to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what you described, in your case you can make use of IHttpClientFactory for creating http clients

```
    public class GrpResponse
    {
        public string client { get; set; }
        public HttpResponseMessage response { get; set; }
    }

    private async void ExecuteGrpRequest()
    {
       var payLoad = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var grpTasks = new List<Task<GrpResponse>>
        {
            SendAsyc("real", payLoad),
            SendAsyc("mock", payLoad)
        };

        var responses = await Task.WhenAll(grpTasks);
    }

    private async Task<GrpResponse> SendAsyc(string client, HttpRequestMessage message )
    {
        // IHttpClientFactory is _httpClientFacotry; injected from ctor
        var httpClient = _httpClientFacotry.CreateClient(client);
        return  new GrpResponse
            {
                client = client,
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage())
            };
    }
```